# drag multiple DIV in a same time without Click or Ctrl Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm stack of this case.

Can anybody help me please?
I want to drag multiple item/DIV in a same time without Clicking/Control Click the item I want to drag. 
That meant, **by default**, the items I want to drag is already "*selected*" when my page is loaded.
I want something like this [this](http://jsfiddle.net/MmWbH/) , I tried it in my local server but it's not working for me.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var selectedClass = 'ui-state-highlight';

    var $draggableElems = $("#draggable div").draggable({
        start: function (e, ui) {
            if (e.target.id == "start") $draggableElems.addClass(selectedClass);
            else return false;
        },
        stop: function (e, ui) {
            // reset group positions
            $('.' + selectedClass).css({
                top: 0,
                left: 0
            });
        },
        drag: function (e, ui) {
            if (e.target.id == "start") {
                // this works because the position is relative to the starting position
                $('.' + selectedClass).css({
                    top: ui.position.top,
                    left: ui.position.left
                });
            }
        }
    });

    $("#droppable").droppable({
        drop: function (e, ui) {
            var $selectedElems = $('.' + selectedClass).remove().clone();
            $selectedElems.appendTo($(this)).add(ui.draggable) // ui.draggable is appended by the script, so add it after
            .removeClass(selectedClass).css({
                top: 0,
                left: 0
            });
        }
    });
});
```

i ll appreciate if somebody can help me

Thanks a lot!

Comment: so what's the problem? the jsFiddle example works fine after including jQuery UI libraries. http://jsfiddle.net/MmWbH/1/

Comment: tks arie. i am the beginner with jquery drag. the problem is which jquery version will used for this code. i add this <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js" ></script>
 in my top code. but its not working

Comment: You also need to include the jQuery UI library after jQuery, you need the Draggable & Droppable plugin to enable drag and drop. Check the official site of [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)

Comment: Try to search more information [here](http://jqueryui.com/).

Comment: tks for the info, its working now. but i need to customize that all. - how to make it all dragged only in horizontal mode. forget about droppable. and i want to modify the position, i meant box 1, box 2 box 3 is separated, and when i want to drag the position is still separated

Comment: I meant, something like this. http://jsfiddle.net/delfi/eCEU3/1/ but the problem is when i drag all 3 boxes the position changed. i want  all the boxes  will follow the location  when it first loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the jQuery UI library, on jsfiddle you just need to check the checkbox that says jQuery UI 1.8.18

```
<script type="text/javascript" src"js/jquery_ui_1.8.18"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MmWbH/2/

Comment: I meant, something like this. http://jsfiddle.net/delfi/eCEU3/1/ but the problem is when i drag all 3 boxes the position changed. i want  all the boxes  will follow the location  when it first loaded.

Comment: Do you mean that it works well for the same code on the jsfiddle, but not working on your server?
Do you see any errors in the console?